# Verify coq theorems in build script?

Tags: command-line, automation, coq

I'm using [coq](http://coq.inria.fr/) to study the meta theory of a programming language.

Composing and verifying theorems interactively in the IDE is all well and good, but I need to automate (re)verification.  I see the man pages, but I don't see this use case spelled out anywhere.

How can I incorporate coq verification into a build script?

Comment: Have you looked into `coqc` and `coqchk`?

Comment: I see them, but a simple example showing their usage together was lacking.  I'm also not worried (yet) about the performance of checking since the theory is still small; an interpreted solution fits better for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have this `metatheory/hello_world.v`:

```
$ cat metatheory/hello_world.v
Theorem hello_world : forall a b:Prop, a /\ b -> b /\ a.
intros a b H.
split.
destruct H as [H1 H2].
exact H1. (* A bug: We actually need H2 here. *)
intuition.
```

Then we can see the error (with failing exit code) with:

```
$ coqtop -batch -silent -l metatheory/hello_world.v
Error while reading metatheory/hello_world.v:
File "/vagrant/metatheory/hello_world.v", line 5, characters 6-8:
Error: In environment
a : Prop
b : Prop
H1 : a
H2 : b
The term "H1" has type "a" while it is expected to have type
"b".
```

If we fix the problem:

```
$ coqtop -batch -silent -l metatheory/hello_world.v
```

..with a successful exit code.